# What does glibc detected ...httpd: double free or corruption mean?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, glibc

I have asked this question on serverfault.com which is as suggested a more appropriate place for it - https://serverfault.com/questions/169829/what-does-glibc-detected-httpd-double-free-or-corruption-mean

---

I have an EC2 server running that I use to process image uploads. i have a flash swf that handles uploading to the server from my local disk - while uploading about 130 images (a total of about 650MB) I got the following error in my server log file after about the 45th image.

*** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x85a6b990 ***

What does this error mean?

The server has stopped responding so I will restart it. Where should I begin to find the cause of this problem?

thanks

some info -

Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8b configured 
Fedora 8

Comment: maybe this should be on http://www.serverfault.com?

Comment: Yes - you are right, Ive copied this question to serverfault.com - http://serverfault.com/questions/169829/what-does-glibc-detected-httpd-double-free-or-corruption-mean - good suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This means your web server has crashed.  Barring bad hardware, this is a bug inside either the Apache server or a module you have loaded (such as mod_php).

Try upgrading to a newer version, if one is available.  If that fails, open a bug report with the Apache maintainers.

Comment: I am wondering if it is something in my code, I have a script that resizes large images then updates a database then copies  the image to S3. if there is a lot of images could it be a problem with my script for example memory issues? I am running the process again on a new instance of the EC2 server and have enabled cloudwatch to check on things. I am currently on my 3rd attempt, the second time the same problem occurred.

Comment: @undefined: regardless of what the client is doing, it should not be able to crash the web server.  This is a bug.